# Working with Events in F#

Tags: wpf, events, f#, system.reactive

I recently asked this question:
[Replay Recorded Data Stream in F#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5372396/replay-recorded-data-stream-in-f) and combined that code with a subset of the functionality I found here:
http://www.mattssoftwareblog.com/?p=271
which combined looks like this:

```
#r "System.Reactive"
#r "System.CoreEx"
#r "FSharp.PowerPack"
#r "WindowsBase"
#r "PresentationCore"
#r "PresentationFramework"
#r "System.Xaml"
#r "System.Interactive.dll"

open System
open System.Linq
open System.Collections.Generic
open System.Net
open System.IO
open System.Threading
open System.Windows
open System.Windows.Input
open System.Windows.Controls
open System.Windows.Shapes
open System.Windows.Media
open System.Xaml
```

I need to use the events generated here (which came from my earlier SO question):

```
let prices = [ (0, 10.0); (1000, 10.5); (500, 9.5); (2500, 8.5); (500, 10.0); (1000, 10.5); (500, 9.5); (2500, 8.5) ]

let evt = new Event<float>()
async { for delay, price in prices do
          do! Async.Sleep(delay)
          evt.Trigger(price) }
        |> Async.StartImmediate

evt.Publish.Add(printfn "Price updated: %A")
```

to use as the data source for the line which is randomly created here (the code below comes from the blog article I mentioned):

```
let create f =
    Observable.Create<_>(fun x ->
        f x
        new System.Action((fun () -> ())))

let fromEvent (event:IEvent<_,_>) = create (fun x -> event.Add x.OnNext)

// Random Walker
let rand = Random()
let mutable m = 0.
let randomWalker() =
    m <- m + (rand.NextDouble() * 10.) - 5.
    m

let timer = new System.Timers.Timer()
timer.Interval <- 100.
let timerObs = (timer.Elapsed |> fromEvent).Select(fun _ -> randomWalker())

let chartWindow = new Window(Height = 600., Width = 600.)
let canvas = new Canvas()
chartWindow.Content <- canvas
chartWindow.Show()

let line xs =
    let segs =
        seq { for x , y in xs |> List.tail ->
                LineSegment(Point(x,y), true) :> PathSegment }
    let (sx, sy) = xs |> List.head
    PathGeometry([PathFigure(Point(sx,sy), segs, false)])

let plot xs (path:Path) =
    let now = DateTime.Now
    let timeSpan = TimeSpan(0,1,0)
    let width = 600.
    let height = 600.
    let pts = xs |> List.map (fun (x:Timestamped<float>) ->
                (600.-(now - (x.Timestamp.DateTime)).TotalMilliseconds * 600. / timeSpan.TotalMilliseconds),x.Value  + 300.)
    path.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new SendOrPostCallback(fun pts -> path.Data <- line (pts :?> (float*float)list)), pts) |> ignore

let trailing (timespan:TimeSpan) (obs:IObservable<'

a>)  =
        obs.Timestamp()
            .Scan([], fun ys x ->
                let now = DateTime.Now
                let timespan = timespan
                x :: (ys |> List.filter (fun x -> (now - x.Timestamp.DateTime) < timespan)))
            .Where(fun xs -> xs |> List.length > 1)

    // Main Path
    let mainPath = new Path(Stroke=Brushes.Blue, StrokeThickness=1.)
    canvas.Children.Add(mainPath)

    let trailingRandomsSub = (timerObs |> trailing (TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60.))).Subscribe(fun xs -> plot xs mainPath)

    timer.Start()
```

If you paste this into an interactive session you will see a blue line emerge which is generated randomly and not using my new `evt` `Event`.  I guess my confusion is not understanding how to make and use an `Observable` from my `evt`.  Basically, how can I make evt my data source for the blue line?

Thanks in advance,

Bob

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In F#, the `IEvent<'T>` interface inherits from `IObservable<'T>`. This means that you can use F# events in any place where an observable is expected.

The last bit of your application (that takes the event, adds time stamps, uses `Scan` to get lists containing the items generated so far and plots the progress) can be written like this:

```
let trailingRandomsSub = 
  evt.Publish.Timestamp()
  |> Observable.scan (fun l e -> e::l) []
  |> Observable.add (fun xs -> plot xs mainPath)
```

F# provides wrappers for some of the Rx functions, so you can use `Observable.scan`, which has a bit more F#-friendly syntax. `Observable.add` is just another syntax for `Subscribe`.

The key difference between F# events and observables is that observables start when you attach a handler. On the other hand, the F# event that you create using `Async.StartImmediate` starts immediately when the `StartImmediate` method is called (this means - to get the sample working, you need to evaluate everything at once, or write a function that starts the event).

Comment: Actually, I suspected that to be the case and tried every substitution/refactoring operation I could think of and simply could not figure out how to make those two code snippets work together.  I suspect the timer might be what is making the integration difficult, but don't know how exactly.

Comment: @Beaker: I was playing with your code a bit and added a sample showing how to setup things in your scenario.

Comment: I think I see what I was doing wrong now.  What is it you changed exactly?

Comment: You mean the function you provided, I thought you meant you changed my code somehow.  I think I need to find a good source of info for learning how to use Rx with F#.  Thanks again Tomas!

Comment: @Beaker: Yes, the code in the answer is all you need. There is a short introduction to Events in F#, Rx and using Async for GUI programming in Chapter 16 of my F# book (http://manning.com/petricek). You can take a look at the source code (http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/realworldfp) to see if there is anything that would interest you...

Comment: I do own a copy of your book, but completely forgot you had that chapter in there.

Comment: @beaker in this code LocalDateTime is the property  to get out of the timestamp